# PHP Missing argument 1 for show_products()

Tags: php, missing-data

I have a PHP function that produces this error:

```
Missing argument 1 for show_products(), called in 
C:\server\htdocs\php\index.php on line 21
```

This is the PHP code:

```
function show_products($cat){
    if(isset($cat)){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `PRODUCTS` WHERE cat = '$cat'";
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `PRODUCTS` WHERE 1";
    }

    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    if($query){
        while ($product = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo $product['name'] . " - " . $product['price'] . "<br />";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "No Product found!";
    }
}
```

I call the function like this:

```
show_products()
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method requires a parameter and you have not supplied one.

If you want to be able to invoke the function with no argument.  Make a default value for your argument `$cat` like this:

```
function show_products($cat = null) {    
    // your code 
}
```

Then when you call the method without an argument, the variable is assigned null.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
function show_products($cat){
...
```

to

```
function show_products($cat = ""){
    if( !empty($cat) ) {
       ....
```

so that your function works even if no argument is passed to it